# $n*k$ children create $k$ circles with $n$ kids each, in how many ways can we arrange such circles?

Tags: combinatorics

If we were to have one circle with $y$ kids, such circle could be formed in $(y-1)!$ ways, since the place of the first kid is fixed, and thus we don't have any other way, than just placing it in a circle and choosing ways to place $y-1$ kids. So I was thinking, that solution for $nk$ kids with $k$ circles and n children in each would be:

$$\binom {nk}{n}*(n-1)! *\binom{nk-n}{n}*(n-1)!*\binom{nk-2n}{n}*(n-1)!*\ldots*1*(n-1)!$$

Is this correct reasoning about that problem?

Comment: Are the circles labeled?  I.e. if we have kids 1,2,3,4 in "the first circle" in that order (*clockwise with 1 at north*) and kids 5,6,7,8 in "the second circle" in that order... is this automatically considered different than if we had kids 5,6,7,8 in "the first circle" in that order and kids 1,2,3,4 in "the second circle"?  Or could these still be considered "the same"?

Comment: In your expression, you begin with a clear pattern, but then finish with an ellipses ($\dots$) followed by multiplication by $1$.  How does that $1$ fit into the pattern you began?  Should it not have ended with an $(n-1)!$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, i forgot about that, i will edit it in a moment

Comment: @JMoravitz (1,2,3,4) (5,6,7,8) circles and (5,6,7,8) (1,2,3,4) is considered the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your circles are labeled and rotations of the circles are considered equivalent, your pattern that you began is all well and good and does lead to a correct answer.  It can be written far more simply however by using the language of multinomial coefficients as

$$\binom{nk}{n,n,n,\dots,n}((n-1)!)^k = \dfrac{(nk)!((n-1)!)^k}{(n!)^k}$$

Noting the relationship between numerator and denominator, we can cancel out a great deal of each giving

$$\dfrac{(nk)!}{n^k}$$

In the event the circles are not meant to be labeled, we can modify the previous expression by "division by symmetry" to correct the count.  Here we divide by the $k!$ ways in which we can label the circles to "forget" which circle is which.  This gives $\dfrac{(nk)!}{(n)^kk!}$

We could also have arrived at the same answer without a "division by symmetry" argument.  We can assume without loss of generality that the children can be totally ordered alphabetically (*with no repeats*).  Let the earliest kid take whatever spot in an available circle, it matters not which.  Now, pick a child to stand to their right, and then another child to stand to that child's right, and so on until the circle is complete.  Then, among the children that are left, one of these children will be earliest alphabetically.  Continue the process letting that child take any open spot in an open circle and filling out the circle, and so on continuing with the earliest child remaining alphabetically for each next iteration of the process.

This gives an answer of $(nk-1)(nk-2)\cdots(nk-n)(nk-n+1)(nk-n-1)(nk-n-2)\cdots$ which you can recognize as $(nk)!$ missing every $n$'th term.  That is, it is $(nk)!$ missing terms $nk, nk-n, nk-2n, nk-3n,\dots$ which you can recognize as the terms in the product of $k!\cdot n^k$ leading to the same final answer as before of

$$\dfrac{(nk)!}{(n)^kk!}$$

Comment: Thank you for your time and comprehensive response :) It's great to see different way of same task solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that we can take.

We line up the $nk$ kids in a single row. First $n$ kids (with their arrangement) make one (ordered) circle, next $n$ make another and so on.

The number of ways we can line up $nk$ kids is given by $(nk)!$.

Now because of the linear arrangement, kids in each group could be arranged among themselves in $n!$ ways but in circular arrangement, that would be only $(n-1)!$. To compensate for that, for each of the $k$ groups, we need to divide by $n$.

So, the number actually becomes

$$\frac{(nk)!}{n^k}$$

Also, if we don't care about the order of the groups / circles (whether a particular circle is the first or at some other position), then we will have to further divide by $k!$, since the $k$ groups can be arranged in $k!$ ways. So,

$$\frac{(nk)!}{n^k \cdot k!}$$

---

Your line of thinking seems correct to me. Only that you may also have to divide by $k!$ if the order of the circles is immaterial.